# What is best practice for deploying an application as static or as dynamic build?

Tags: c++, windows, deployment, wxwidgets

I am planning to release and deploy an application, written in C++ and wxWidgets. The wxWidgets-library is available as dll and as well as static library. Therefore, i have the option to deploy the application as dynamic built application or as static build.

Currently, i prefer the static-build option, because:

- the executable is not too big ( < 20 MegaByte).
- there are no dependencies to consider.
- there is no installation required.

**Question**

Did i miss something very important?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be to go for **static linkage**. My two cents on advantage:

- You aren't dependent on WX toolset being installed on client site, neither you need to give it bundled with your installer, not as standalone installer as a **prerequisite**.
- You don't expect or ask the customer to do WX installation (or even `XCOPY` deployment). Customer won't bother!
- 20MBs is quite small in TBs of world and good MBs of Internet speed.
- You don't get unexpected behavior bugs from customer, if they happen to use higher/lower version of library.
- You can be confident that application will work the same way you tested in your environment (mostly)
- You can continue using X version of WX, even if buggy/flashy X+1 version comes out. You don't want to let customer have "newer and refined" version of library, which breaks your app!

Answer (score 7):

You should use dynamic linking when there is a good reason to use it and static linking otherwise. Some good reasons to use dynamic linking are:

1. You're distributing binaries for a system which already has or, may have, wxWidgets libraries such as a number of Linux distributions, OS X (with Homebrew) etc. In this case it is strongly preferable to reuse the existing system libraries rather than using your own ones.
2. You have several modules using wxWidgets: space saving from using dynamic linking may be quite significant here.
3. You use wxWidgets from a DLL under MSW: in this case wxWidgets itself should also be linked as a DLL, otherwise you risk having problems if more than one instance of wxWidgets is loaded into the process address space.
4. You plan on updating the installation of your application via network: in this case it may be nice to be able to update just a single DLL instead of a whole monolithic application.

If neither of these reasons apply, e.g. you just want to distribute a single program under MSW, static linking is simpler and so preferable.

A related note: if you do end up distributing wxWidgets DLLs, consider using a unique suffix for them instead of "custom" used by default, this will reduce the chances of confusion between your DLLs and some other version of wx.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst in your case the executable isn't very big, it can get extremely large if you link everything statically. It also uses more memory, as the larger executable has to be loaded into memory.

If you were to use a dynamic library, the operating system can "share" the read only memory from each between processes, lowering your memory requirements.

Updating your application can also be easier with a dynamic library, as rather than having to update the entire executable you can just swap out the dynamic library (assuming its interface is the same) and voila! The same applies if the user wants to update their dynamic library (for example, via a package manager).